# How to save a value from didSelectRowAtIndexPath and carry it to another tableView (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my first table view I have an array which populates the table view. The user then clicks a cell. Each cell has a different text label. I want to carry the label value from one table view to the next, but when it gets to the other table view the variable I try to set it to is nil. I am using segues and have tried to use prepareForSeguge function. I just can't get the variable to save once it's left the didSelectRowatIndexPath method.

EDIT: I used an observer to check that my variable was being set, but it isn't set until after all other functions have run. How Would I then be able to use my variable in my second tableview to populate the table?

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    GenreSelector = currentCell.textLabel!.text

    print(GenreSelector)

    performSegueWithIdentifier("letsGo", sender: self)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "letsGo") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultTableViewController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.GenreSelection = GenreSelector
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Make sure all the properties involved are non-weak and that ResultTableViewController.GenreSelection doesn't get set anywhere else. You can also debug with a didSet observer if breakpoints aren't helping.

Comment: The Variables that were used there are `var ResultArray: [NSObject] = [] and
    var GenreSelection:String?` Which I think are strongly typed as is the variable I am sending to.

Comment: Yes, unless you specifically add weak, properties are strong by default. If the code in prepareForSegue gets called correctly, I suspect the property gets set back to nil someplace else, and a property observer is your best bet for catching it when it happens.

Comment: so i put a property observer on the second veiwController and the value does make it over, I just need to access it in the right function I guess. It isn't said when the view loads however.

Comment: That's definitely possible if you access the view in the initializer for example. It should definitely be there by the time viewWillAppear gets called.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say it isn't set when the viewDidload is called. I tried a print statement there and it returns nil. and I just realized you meant veiwWillAppear not viewDidAppear.